# write binary file to docx file

Tags: c#, linq

I save docx file in database as a binary file ,i save it and there isn't any problems but my problem is : when i want to retrieve my binary data and convert it to a docx file ,i don't know what should i do ,i read byte data from database but i don't know how should i save that :

```
   var q = (from i in pn.tblLetters
                    where i.letterId == 1
                    select i).First();

            byte[] res = q.letterContent.ToArray();
```

my docx file saved in tblletters in database and i read that and save it in res variable

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you've got it in a byte array, all you need to do is write it to a file:

```
File.WriteAllBytes(@"C:\temp\myfile.docx", res);
```